# TypeError: list indices must be integers

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm trying to insert an item from one list to another and using an item from a list of numbers for the index but I'm getting this error even though I'm using integers for index numbers

and the other thing is that the same item is accepted as an index in the line just before the error

I even tried putting a number there just to test it but it gave me the same error

here's the code:

```
FoundLetters = ['p', 'l', '-', 'i', 'n']
MissingLetters = []
AllLetters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n',
              'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']


def MissingCount():
    for j in range(len(FoundLetters)):
        if FoundLetters[j] == '-':
            MissingLetters.append(int(j))


def iterate():
    for i in range(len(AllLetters)):
        for i in AllLetters:
            FoundLetters.pop(MissingLetters[0])
            FoundLetters.insert(MissingLetters[0], AllLetters[i])


MissingCount()
iterate()
```

and this was the exact error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 26, in <module>
iterate()
File "main.py", line 22, in iterate
FoundLetters.insert(MissingLetters[0], AllLetters[i])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str


** Process exited - Return Code: 1 **
Press Enter to exit terminal
```

Comment: In your *iterate()* function you have an outer and an inner loop both utilising *i*. That variable will be a string in the inner loop

Comment: the problem is in these two lines: `for i in range(len(AllLetters)):` and `for i in AllLetters:`. You are using the same variable `i` in 2 nested loops.

Comment: I think you have more than one bug going on here, and I also think there's probably a much easier way to do whatever you're trying to do.  Can you explain what the final result is supposed to be?

Comment: @LancelotduLac ohh thanks got it now, that fixed it

Comment: Looks like the pop/insert technique might be flawed. Please explain **exactly** what you're trying to achieve. There has to be a better way

Comment: @Samwise I'm trying to write a program that tries to complete a word with a few letters missing by trying all the possible combinations and then checking each of them with the English-words library and then printing them if it's an actual word. this is just the part of the code I had a problem with I can send you the full code if you want

Comment: @LancelotduLac just added some more explanation in a comment here

Comment: What's the output of *this part of the code* supposed to be?  What do you want `FoundLetters` and `MissingLetters` to contain after `iterate()` is done?  Are you just trying to generate a list of strings like `["plain", "plbin", "plcin", ...]`?

Comment: @samwise to generate a list of strings like you mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem with your code is that you are using i twice in the iterate function. So you are overwriting the first i. Therefore you are looping through  AlLLetters and you try to index AllLeters with strings like "a". Try to change the second loop

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using `itertools.product` to generate all the possible replacement combinations:

```
import itertools
import string

found_letters = "pl-in"
missing_indices = [i for i, c in enumerate(found_letters) if c == "-"]

possible_words = (''.join(
    r[i] if i in r else c
    for i, c in enumerate(found_letters)
) for r in (
    dict(zip(missing_indices, p))
    for p in itertools.product(
        string.ascii_lowercase,
        repeat=len(missing_indices)
    )
))

print(list(possible_words))  # ['plain', 'plbin', ...]
```

Using `repeat` with the number of missing letters will allow this to work regardless of the number of missing letters.  In the above code, `p` is a product (`'a'`, `'b'`, ...) and `r` is the replacement map for a given product (`{2: 'a'}`, `{2: 'b'}`, ...).  When there are multiple `-`s in `found_letters`, each `p` will have that many letters (`'aa'`, `'ab'`, ...) and `r` will map the location of each `-` to the letter that should replace it (`{2: 'a', 4: 'a'}`, `{2: 'a', 4: 'b'}`, ...).

Note that the sequence of `possible_words` will get very large very quick if you have a lot of missing letters because it's exponential!  Although it's convenient to turn it into a `list` when you want to print the whole thing, you may want to leave it in generator form so you can filter it through the English dictionary and drop all the nonsense words as you see them.

Comment: Thank you! I did try to use this but I couldn't figure out how to, I'll try to see if I can rewrite the code using this

Comment: Rewrote it as a generator expression so it doesn't necessarily have to go in a giant list.  :D